# Closing an IE instance created by WScript.CreateObject

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, automation, wmi

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the process ID from an object that was created by running:

```
Set ie = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "ie_")
```

My problem is that sometimes I see that the `iexplorer` process remains open and isn't closed after running:

```
ie.stop
ie.Quit
```

I found some workarounds, like looking for the newest `iexplorer` process or looking at the process name, but this isn't good for me since I have several Internet Explorer instances opened in parallel by different processes and it might be on the same time.

This is not good:

```
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
("Select * from Win32_Process Where " _ 
& "Name = '"& sProcessName & "'")
```

I saw [this solution](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=379959) that might work, but I don't know how to implement it for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Without calling a powershell command or using com wrapper you may want filter processes by its command line. An iexplorer.exe process which created from dcom launch has a commandline like `-Embedding`. A sample query about what I meant.

> Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = 'iexplore.exe' And CommandLine Like '%-Embedding'

Yes I heard you, this will returns all embedded instances so it may not be useful if there are multiple instances.

An IE object instance has a property that returns mainwindowhandle : [HWND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

What can be done to terminate more reliable using HWND :

Running a command from Powershell:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strCommand = "powershell -Command ""Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowHandle -eq "& IE.Hwnd &"} | kill"""
WshShell.Run strCommand, vbHide, True
```

Using / writing a component that wraps Windows APIs something like that (32 bit only): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16558/DestroyWindow-in-VBScript

```
Set obj = CreateObject("APIWrapperCOM.APIWrapper")
    obj.KillWindow IE.Hwnd
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent. sometimes i saw that the navigate opens my site in a "regular" internet explorer and not in the window that was created by the Application.internetexplorer. It happened when i call with the "_self" flag...

Can you think of a reason why? in this case the kill will not help

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for this one
I've tested it in a Powershell Object so It should be the same thing.

```
$ie.Quit()
```